# How to connect to local Python server from Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm attempting to connect to a locally hosted Python server from the Android Studio emulator. When I try from the emulator's browser, I receive 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. If I try connecting through the host machine's browser or linux terminal, I have no issues. Below is the code for the server as well as my Android manifest file.

If it matters: IDE is Android Studio (bad I know), OS is Pop_OS

**Server**

```
import socket


# get the hostname
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8800  # initiate port no above 1024
print('Server On')
server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
# look closely. The bind() function takes tuple as argument
server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together

# configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
server_socket.listen(2)
conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
print("Connection from: " + str(address))
while True:
    # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
        # if data is not received break
        break
    print("from connected user: " + str(data))
    #data = input(' -> ')
    #conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

conn.close()  # close the connection
```

**app/src/degub/manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.palm_trimmer">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: 1.) Where are you running the server (emulator or dev box)? 2.) What is its address? 3.) What address are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @greeble31 I'm running the Python server on my host machine from a terminal and attempting to connect to it from the Android emulator. The goal is to create an app that sends strings (like 'up') to the server, but first I have to resolve this issue.

Apparently, the IP to reference for the emu is '10.0.2.2' as it is a built in loopback provided for development.

Comment: You might try Wiresharking it, but `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` implies the socket connected to the target address, and the server responded "I don't have anybody listening on [the requested port number]".

Comment: @greeble31 I don't have Wireshark at the moment but using nmap to scan the host machine revealed that all the ports are closed, except for two. Upon changing the Python server's port to one of those, it works! Thank you for the suggestion, would've never thought of it!

Comment: Something doesn't sound right there, but glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @greeble31's suggestion, I checked the port status of my host machine (using nmap) and found that the port I bound the server to was not open. After replacing port '8888' with one of the open ones, I was able to successfully connect the emulator to the localhost.